# Unifying ToolstripButtons and ToolstripMenuItems

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip, menustrip

Almost in all cases, `ToolStripItems` do just what their equivalent `MenuStripItem` do. In these cases, `ToolTip`, `icon` and `text` of these two commands are the same. So, is there any way (preferably a .NET native way) to synchronize and unify these two items? This might be a way to define commands somewhere else and just put them into various strips.

Comment: I am not clear on what you mean by unifying the items and what exactly you want to achieve. They both inherit from ToolStripItem, so that is a common point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) which will allow you to encapsulate the logic that you want to call from both the `ToolStripButton` and `MenuStripItem`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15047/577417) Stackoverflow post provides some examples of implementing the command pattern in .net and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5010361/577417) answer I provided shows how to provide a generic way of binding commands to buttons (this can be very easily adapted to work with other controls such as `ToolStripItem`).

There is an `ICommand` interface for use with WPF but there is no reason why you cant use it in your Windows Forms application.

Finally, if you want to provide other common properties for the command such as command text or an image I would suggest deriving a new interface from the `ICommand` interface (for eaxample, called `IUICommand`) which provides these properties. It won't take much effort to enhance the `CommandBinding` class shown in the link to set the appropriate properties in your `ToolStripItem`.